После обновления GIT в терминале PyCharm (и других продуктах JB) криво отображается кириллица
После обновления GIT кириллица стала отображаться так (как напрямую в C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe, так и в терминале PyCharm, где в терминале в качестве оболочки также используется bash.exe).
$ git commit -m 'Текст на русском языке'
[master 06b7026] ╨в╨╡├С╨║╤Б╤В ╨╜╨░ ╤А╤Г╤Б╤Б╨║╨╛╨╝ ╤П╨╖╤Л╨║╨╡├С├С├С
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

При этом в логи попадает русский язык, но с примесями какого-то мусора.
$ git log -1 --oneline
06b7026 (HEAD -> master) ТеÑкст на русском языкеÑÑÑ

Мусор тем вероятнее появится, если ввести символ, потом удалить его и набрать новый.
Вопрос: как починить работу GIT'а в консоли PyCharm?
Ранее проблем такого рода не было, обновлений Windows не было, обновление PyCharm до актуальной версии проблему не сняло.
Проблему вижу при использовании C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe. При использовании C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe проблемы нет:
$ git commit -m 'Текст на русском'
[master b8f995a] Текст на русском
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git log -1 --oneline
b8f995a (HEAD -> master) Текст на русском

Пациент:

Windows 11 Домашняя для одного языка,
PyCharm 2024.1,
GIT 2.44.0.windows.1.

Настройки PyCharm сейчас такие:

Settings -> Tools -> Terminal -> Shell path — путь к установленному гиту: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe.
Settings -> Editor -> General -> Console -> Default Encoding — UTF-8
Help -> Edit Custom VM Options добавлены отельными строками: -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8 и -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8


Похоже на проблему с конкретной версией GIT. Откатился до git version 2.43.0.windows.1, проблема с непонятной кодировкой ушла.
